# Control timeout for a CURL call doesn't work

Tags: php, curl, timeout

I need to make a call to an external service using CURL, the problem is that sometimes it takes a long response time, and my page is suspended until it receives response.

I used the CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT and CURLOPT_TIMEOUT options but has no effect. I read that CURL, also makes use of the "default_socket_timeout" variable, but still the request always takes 55 seconds before being canceled.

It seems like CURL ignore any option or configuration.

```
ini_set("max_execution_time", 10);
ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 10);
set_time_limit(5);

$start = time();

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/test/sleep.php');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 5);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 8);

curl_exec($curl);

$end = time() - $start;
echo '>>>'.$end.'<<<';
```

Output:

```
>>>55<<
```

**Note:** *sleep.php* only have an infinite loop. And I see that in the server:  max_execution_time was 60 and default_socket_timeout was 30 before I changed it to 10 seconds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP cURL timeout ignored](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801795/php-curl-timeout-ignored)

Answer (score 1):

your configuration is correct and works as expected. the problem is that curl IS able to connect to your script (sleep.php) so the connection timeout isn't triggered. The 55 seconds are probably from the max_execution_time.

try to connect to a random ip-address instead of localhost and you will see that the connection-timeout is working.

edit:
also the CURLOPT_TIMEOUT is working, I have testet it with an script which contains an infinit loop and the curl-request gets stopped after 8 sec.

Comment: Hi, Can you show me your infinite loop script? That's mine:

<?php for(;;) sleep(1); ?>

Comment: By the way,

max_execution_time has the value 10, and if I execute a ini_get('max_execution_time') returns 10. The 55 isn't max_execution_time configuration.

I Just throw the script and now i get  >>110<<

Comment: <?php
ini_set("max_execution_time", 10);

while(1){

}
exit;

which php-version are you using? I read something about a bug in curl-lib in older php-versions and it seems that the timeout gets ignored because of that bug

Comment: $ php --version
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.13 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jul  7 2014 18:54:55) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group

Comment: strange...I'm using the same php-version - which curl-version are you using? (you can see it with phpinfo(); -> curl section)

Comment: I'm using the exact same cURL-version. Are you sure that it's not working? Try to simplify your testcase and remove all options and ini_set's, then add them gradually.
the only differents between you'r environment is that I'm not using the Suhosin-Patch - maybe this is causing the problem